# Counting words in each sentence using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, word-count

I need to create a program that shows a sentence with the most words in it.

```
string [] st = { "I like apples.", 
                 "I like red apples.", 
                 "I like red apples than green apples." 
};

foreach (string s in st)
{
    int NumberOfWords = s.Split(' ').Length;
}
```

The result should be displaying "I like red apples than green apples".

Comment: What have you tried? Show something (anything), even if it's not working, so someone here can help you improve it.

Comment: The best place to begin would be to break down the problem into smaller sub-problems. Then tackle each sub-problem independently.

Comment: This is rather easy to do with string.split(). You should show us something that you have tried so we can help with a specific problem. This site is not a please code this for me type of site.

Comment: Hi guys, I've added my code....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you have the sentences in different `TextBox` control in your Form. For you to know which sentence have more words in it; split the sentence by space and get a count of words and then you can compare. something like below.

```
int str1 = "I like apples".Split(' ').Length;
int str2 = "I like red apples".Split(' ').Length;
int str3 = "I like red apples than green apples".Split(' ').Length;
```

Here `split()` functions returns a string array and so you can get `Length` of it. Now you can compare them easily.

**EDIT:**

Below would be a full example code drawn over your posted code. Store the word count in a `int[]` array. Then sort the array. Obviously the last element in `arr` below would be the one having highest words.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[3];           
        string[] st = { "I like apples.", "I like red apples.", 
                             "I like red apples than green apples." };
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (string s in st)
        {
            int NumberOfWords = s.Split(' ').Length;
            arr[counter] = NumberOfWords;
            counter++;
        }

        Array.Sort(arr);

        Console.WriteLine(st[arr.Length - 1]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul! Will try and get back to you soon! But... maybe it sounds silly but could display the result in Label? Anyway, will try~

Comment: Yes, just attach it to Label `Text` property like `this.label1.Text = st[arr.Length - 1]`

Comment: Thanks Rahul! I can't thank you enough! It worked great! and your code is not hard to understand! Thanks for your help again~

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = st
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.Split(' ').Count())
    .First();
```

Comment: Hi Mihai, thanks for your solution but my lack of C# knowledge doesn't recognize what "var" means in C#...(i've seen it in javascript) I've seen OrderByDescending and it looks handy solution but I won't be able to test it with the part of code....I only can blame myself.... but thanks for your code :) I might be able to use in it the future~

Comment: @user3601310, oh, you can replace `var` with `string` in the above example. `var` means your compiler will infer the type of the variable for you, based on what's on the right side (here `First()` will return the first `string` from a sequence of strings ordered by length). So the return type will be string. If you hover your mouse over the `result` variable, you'll see that it's interpreted as a string.

Comment: Hi Mihai, seems like it's gonna work but I got an error under s and sorry but don't know how to display it...                         string[] st = { "I like apples. I like red apples. I like red apples than green apples." };
            foreach (string s in st)
            { 
                string result = st.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First();
            }
            this.label1.Text = st.ToString();

Comment: Hi Mihai! Thanks and it worked great! so many ways to get the same result, yours is even easier! Thanks for the time you spent on my question~ But I don't get the s... we haven't declare the s but it works fine...Here is my code : string[] st = { "I like apples.", "I like red apples.", "I like red apples than green apples." };
           
                string result = st.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First();
                this.label1.Text = result;

Comment: @user3601310, as I understand, you want `this.label1.Text` to contain the longest string in `st`. You don't need the `foreach` for that. You only need the result as I've written in my response, and then `this.label1.Text = result`. That's it.

Comment: @user3601310 please check [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). The `s` is declared right there where you see it. The `s => ...` is actually a function. Also, please consider changing your accepted answer if you find this answer more useful to you.

Comment: Hi Mihai, thanks for the explanation, now I get it :) but so sorry I should leave the accepted answer as it is because it was the first helpful answer... but I really appreciate your help! I wish I could tick more than one answer...sorry again...

Comment: This solution will return the sentence with the most chars (letters/whitespace etc), not the sentence with the most words. In your case the sentence with the most words is the same as the one with the most chars, but this will not always be the case..

Comment: @TDull, you're totally right. Thanks for pointing this out. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: @Mihai, that should do it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is quite good if you read its documented summary then you will see `s.Split()` will return the `substring`containing the specified character. But if it is empty then you will get the number of words. So you can use it as:

```
int NumberOfWords = s.Split().Length;
```

Please Share the result.

EDIT:
Before your loop declare an integer

```
int largest = 0;
```

Then in your loop write the code as

```
int NumberOfWords = s.Split().Length;
if(NumberOfWords > largest)
{
   this.label1.Text = s;
   largest = NumberOfWords;
}
```

By this you will get the string with larges words in the `Text` of your `Label`

Comment: Hi Ammar, thanks for your solution but I can't get the result displayed... I used this.label1.Text = st.ToString(); as other user suggested but it shows system somthing... My lack of C# knowledge is killing me.... but thanks for your time thou~

Comment: Please check the details after I EDIT the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick one-liner using Linq:

```
return st.Select(s => s.Split(' ')).OrderByDescending(a => a.Length).First().Aggregate((s, next) => s + " " + next);
```

So essentially we take 4 seperate operations and using Linq turn them into one statement.

1. Turn the string array into an enumeration of string arrays where each string is now an array of its own split on the space character.
2. Order the array (of arrays) by the length of each array (number of words) in descending order (largest, or longest, first).
3. Select the first array (the longest).
4. Take the array (your original string broken into an array of words) and join it back together into a single string.

In a class this may look like:

```
public string LongestString(params string[] args)
{
        return args.Select(s => s.Split(' ')).OrderByDescending(a => a.Length).FirstOrDefault().Aggregate((s, next) => s + " " + next);
}
```

You'll want to make sure you include the Linq namespace by including a "using System.Linq;" at the top of your file (if it's not already there).

Comment: Hi Zachary, man... I wish I could understand Linq..... I can create a simple DB driven website using C# (so I thought I knew a little about C#) but I can't even do simple program like this(considered as simple but to me NO WAY...)...Thanks for your step by step explanation and the time you took to write the solution!

Comment: Happy to help; can't know everything right. Linq became my best friend once I became comfortable with lambdas; it makes working with arrays and enumerations (collections, lists) easier, cleaner, and faster. Definitely worth checking out next time you need do any logic against an array or enumeration of objects. =D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex.Matches()` to get the number of words just like the following example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    const string t1 = "To be or not to be, that is the question.";
    Console.WriteLine(WordCounting.CountWords1(t1));

    const string t2 = "Mary had a little lamb.";
    Console.WriteLine(WordCounting.CountWords1(t2));
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Contains methods for counting words.
/// </summary>
public static class WordCounting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Count words with Regex.
    /// </summary>
    public static int CountWords1(string s)
    {
        MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(s, @"[\S]+");
        return collection.Count;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```cs
var text = @"This is some random text for testing";
var counts = text
    .Where(c => char.IsLetter(c)) // Make sure it's only a letter
    .Select(c => char.ToUpper(c)) // uppercase it
    .GroupBy(c => c) // Group the letters
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        Character = g.Key, 
        Count = g.Count(),
    }) // Select into char and count to make accessing easier
    .OrderBy(x => x.Character); // Order alphabetically
    
foreach (var c in counts)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Letter: {c.Character}\t Count: {c.Count}");
}
```

[image: output]