# How to count the number of words?

Tags: c#, textbox, count, label

I was able to count the number of characters in the textbox. But I do not know how to count the number of words and print them to lable.

Comment: You must be looking for [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794416/counting-words-in-each-sentence-using-c-sharp/26794798#26794798)

Comment: I mean that I have a textbox "My name is Lukas'
I wrote that I lable 4 words

Comment: @lukaszskrzypczak: how many words: `my name is:lukas,my sister is hannah.`

Comment: Please Explain! what else you want. As the word counting mechanism exists in the given link

Comment: Each word must be followed by a space, is a grammatical rule hence in your example, the words are 5.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are differentiating each word with a space, Try this:-

```
int count = YourtextBoxId.Text
                         .Split(new char[] {' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                         .Count();
```

Okay as suggested by @Tim Schmelter, if you have different knids of separator apart from a blank space, you can extend this :-

```
int count = YourtextBoxId.Text
               .Split(new char[] {' ','.',':'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Count();
```

Comment: A space as separator is not enough: `my name is:lukas,my sister is hannah` 6 words? However, you can extend the list for `Split` easily: `.Split(new char[] {' ', ':', '.'}`

Comment: If a text contains a million of the space, you will got a million of strings in the memory. GC likes you :)

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh - `Textbox` text contains millions of space? Sounds unrealistic.

Comment: Multi line textbox of the text editor app can

Answer (score 4):

The first point is the definition of the "WORD" you should know it before implementing a code.

So if the WORD defined as a sequence of letters, you can use the following code to calculate words count:

```
public int WordsCount(string text)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    var count = 0;
    var word = false;

    foreach (char symbol in text)
    {
        if (!char.IsLetter(symbol))
        {
            word = false;
            continue;
        }

        if (word)
        {
            continue;
        }

        count++;
        word = true;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: +1 `Char.IsLetter` excludes punctuation characters like `.`, `,`,`:`,`-` etc., so this is a good idea that also doesn't need to create temporary strings like `String.Split`. A minor improvement: use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead of `string.IsNullOrEmpty`.

Comment: You are right the usage of the IsNullOrWhiteSpace is good idea.
But it will decrease performance for source which starts from a lot of spaces and finish by single words.

Comment: That's premature optimization and a really rare edge-case.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm completely agree with you

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Regex.Matches()` just like the following example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    const string t1 = "To be or not to be, that is the question.";
    Console.WriteLine(WordCounting.CountWords1(t1));
    Console.WriteLine(WordCounting.CountWords2(t1));

    const string t2 = "Mary had a little lamb.";
    Console.WriteLine(WordCounting.CountWords1(t2));
    Console.WriteLine(WordCounting.CountWords2(t2));
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Contains methods for counting words.
/// </summary>
public static class WordCounting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Count words with Regex.
    /// </summary>
    public static int CountWords1(string s)
    {
    MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(s, @"[\S]+");
    return collection.Count;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Count word with loop and character tests.
    /// </summary>
    public static int CountWords2(string s)
    {
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(s[i - 1]) == true)
        {
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(s[i]) == true ||
            char.IsPunctuation(s[i]))
        {
            c++;
        }
        }
    }
    if (s.Length > 2)
    {
        c++;
    }
    return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MyTextbox.Text.Split(' ').Count()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to split the string in the textbox using the spaces.

```
string[] words = textbox.Text.Split(' '); // <-- Space character
int numberOfWords = words.Length;
label.Text = "Number of words are: " + numberOfWords;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me..

```
var noOfWords = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+", " ")
                .Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Length;
```